# Can't import pug in vuejs script tag

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, pug

I'm trying to compile a string of pug to html, so i tried to import pug within vue template but it keeps erroring out.

> import pug from 'pug';

So the main error is that it says that it can't find fs module, i tried to install it but without success. i also tried to add this in my webpack config:

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.pug$/,
          oneOf: [
            // this applies to `<template lang="pug">` in Vue components
            {
              resourceQuery: /^\?vue/,
              use: ['pug-plain-loader']
            },
            // this applies to pug imports inside JavaScript
            {
              use: ['raw-loader', 'pug-plain-loader']
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
})
```

Ans still no resuls :/

Comment: pug is a server-side rendering toolset, vue.js runs in the browser.  Think of pug as a preprocessor for vue.js, as they don't work at the same time, therefore what you're asking for is practically impossible (or at best is massively different from how these two tools are commonly used)

Comment: @Graham [Vue templates support pug template syntax](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html#Introduction).  Please add your Vue template.  Or am I misunderstanding what this question is trying to do?

Comment: Hi @Graham, @zero298, In fact all i'm trying to do is parse a pug string such as `big\n\tbig\n\t\tb hello` to html. in order to do that i need to use `pug.compile` so i have to import pug library in my .vue file: `import pug from pug` but this engenders an errr.

Comment: @zero298 yes, I think you're misunderstanding this a little.  We're using pug very successfully with vue.js and there is indeed a specific order of processing.

Comment: @AbouhassaneAbdelhamid you can't import pug into your vue file as the pug is processed on the server, not the client.  Vue imports are (effectively) processed on the client.  Server-side vue.js would work differently of course, but I'm assuming you're using vue.js in the standard mode.

Comment: The issue might also have to do with the fact that you don't need "pug", you need "pug-loader" ([link](https://github.com/pugjs/pug-loader))

Comment: but why in this example that i found, the importing of pug works? is it because it's processed server-side? https://codepen.io/getflourish/pres/KWRNKr

Comment: Sure, but did you notice the first line: "While not recommended to use on a production website, the standalone version of Pug can be used to compile any string template at runtime"?  As I said above, it's very far from best practices for these tools.